# How can I use this JSON string in js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JSON and js.

I am hand crafting what I think is a valid JSON string and then sending it to a browser via websockets where I assigning it to a js var.

2 questions:

1. Is my JSON string that I am creating correct?
2. What do I need to do in js to be able to parse it and work with each of the key:value pairs?

An example of a string I am sending to the browser: -- Is this string valid?

```
    {"CMD":"XXX"},{"K1A":"V1A","K1B":"V1B"},{"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}
```

Thanks.

Update question:

I have added the brackets.  Thanks for that.

I tried to keep my example simple but it did not convey what I wanted.

CMD is a database CMD to reply with a series of database records.

In my example -- the K1 pairs is one data base record with 2 fields.

The K2 pairs are another set of database records.

In the js code in the browser, I need to parse out each database record ans then parse each if the fields within that database record.

Assuming the brackets are in-place, it THAT string THEN a good string to allow js to extract what I stated above?

Can you provide a code example on how to extract each record and then each field within the record.

Sorry I did not fully explain at first post.

Comment: Thats not a valid json string, if you want to loop over it, you should send something as follow: `[{"CMD":"XXX"},{"K1A":"V1A","K1B":"V1B"},{"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid JSON :

```
   [
      {"CMD":"XXX"},{"K1A":"V1A","K1B":"V1B"},     {"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}
  ]
```

Use

```
   JSON.parse(myjson)
```

To parse your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my JSON string that I am creating correct?

No, you need to wrap the objects in an array.

> What do I need to do in js to be able to parse it and work with each
>   of the key:value pairs?

The data is usable if you simply store it in a variable.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "CMD": "XXX"
  },
  {
    "K1A": "V1A",
    "K1B": "V1B"
  },
  {
    "K2A": "V2A",
    "K2B": "V2B"
  }
];

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array, so you have to add [] before and after the item; however it look like that the array is used just for the value; so i believe that you have to define something similar:

```
let data = {
    "cmd": "xxx",
    "k1": ["v1a", "v2a"],
    "k2": ["v1b", "v2b"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to make it a valid JSON object, we need to wrap your objects in Array.

```
const myJson = [{"CMD":"XXX"},{"K1A":"V1A","K1B":"V1B"},{"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}]
```

And now to read that data, you can do it like this:

```
console.log(myJson[0].CMD); // take first object in array, and return value for CMD key
// You can get same result by accessing using [key]
console.log(myJson[1]['K1A']; // take second object in array, and return value for 'K1A'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a valid json it should have a parent bracket because a json always needs to have a key, and in your case you have multiple json structures:

```
[
  {"CMD":"XXX"},
  {
    "K1A":"V1A",
    "K1B":"V1B"
  },
  {"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}
]
```

if you have this assigned to a variable you can do as as such to stringify it:

```
var myJson = [ your_json ];
var stringifiedMyJson = JSON.stringify(myJson);
```

in your case, to parse it, since it would be an array, you can do a foreach:

```
var myJson = [ your_json ];

myJson.forEach(json => { console.log(json) });
```

This should give you a head start :)

A json fiddle to help:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lbgtv8f2/

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Ele already pointed out, this is incorrect JSON. Wrapping the "JSON" inside an array should suffice. This can be done by using JSON.parse method.

   `var your_object = JSON.parse(json_text);`
2. You can loop through your JSON in multiple ways. Here are 2 examples.

a. Using a for loop

> ```
> for (var key in json) {   
>   if (json.hasOwnProperty(key))  {  
>     alert(json[key].id);    
>     alert(json[key].msg);   
>   }   
> }
> ```

b. Or a forEach (not supported in IE)

> ```
> json.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.id); });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any totally correct answers above.

Here is what works the way I was looking for:

Add [] as stated in ALL posts above

```
     var J = JSON.parse("[{"CMD":"XXX"},{"K1A":"V1A","K1B":"V1B"},{"K2A":"V2A","K2B":"V2B"}]");
```

Now I can get what I want:

```
var CMD = J[0]['CMD'];
var K1A = J[1]['K1A'];
var K2B = J[2]['K2B'];
```

Thanks for all your comments